# Congruence question and prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number when $p-1=2^{s}\cdot t$, $s\in \mathbb{N}, t\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t $ is odd. Need to prove that if $(a,p)=1$, then $a^{t}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$  or $a^{2^{i}\cdot t}\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, for $0\le i\le s-1$. In addition $a\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

---

My attempt: suppose that $(a,p)=1$ and $p-1=2^{s}\cdot t$. Since $0\le i\le s-1$ then let $s=i+x$, for $x\in \mathbb{N}$. According to little's Fermat theorem, since $(a,p)=1$ we have that: $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Recall that $p-1=2^{s}\cdot t$ so by substitution - $a^{p-1}\equiv a^{2^{s}\cdot t}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Now by substitution of $s=i+x$ we get: $a^{2^{i}\cdot 2^{x}\cdot t}\equiv (a^{2^{i}\cdot 2^{x}})^{t}\equiv (a^{2^{i}\cdot t})^{2^{x}}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. From here I don't know how to proceed, but I still didn't use the definition of t and p being odd prime numbers. Therefore I will be glad to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $t$ is odd but not necessarily prime (to clarify your last remark there). And you did use  the primality of $p$ once anyway, in invoking Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Joffan yes yes, I have remarked that on the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\ a^{2^st}\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $, then $\ \left(a^{2^{s-1}t}-1\right)\left(a^{2^{s-1}t}+1\right)\equiv$$0\pmod{p}\ $, so either $\ a^{2^{s-1}t}\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $ or $\ a^{2^{s-1}t}\equiv-1\pmod{p}\ $. If the second alternative holds, you're home.  Otherwise, now play the same game with $\ s-1\ $ in place of $\ s\ $.

**Hint for another approach**

Here's another approach which you might find easier.  The multiplicative order $\ \sigma\ $ of $\ a\ $ mod $\ p\ $ must be a divisor of $\ p-1=2^st\ $—that is $\ \sigma=2^jv\ $, where $\ 0\le j\le s\ $ and $\ t=vw\ $ with $\ v\ $ and $\ w\ $ both odd. If $\ j=0\ $, what is $\ a^v\pmod{p}\ $? What then is $\ a^{vw}=a^t\pmod{p}\ $? If $\ j\ge1\ $ and $\ i=j-1\ $, what is $\ a^{2^iv}\pmod{p}\ $? What then is $\ a^{2^ivw}=a^{2^it}\pmod{p}\ $?

Comment: I thought exactly doing so, but I don't know why I have changed my mind. Thanks! I am gonna give the hint a try.

Comment: Do I need to divide it into cases of $s$? when $s=1$ and $s\neq 1$?
I cannot see.

Comment: Define $\ u=\min\left\{j\in\{0,1,\dots,s\}\,|\,a^{2^jt}\equiv1 \pmod{p}\right\}\ $. Since the set $\ \left\{j\in\{0,1,\dots,s\}\,|\,a^{2^jt}\equiv1 \pmod{p}\right\}\ $ is finite and non-empty (since $\ s\ $ is in it), its minimum is well defined, and belongs to the set. If $\ u=0\ $, what is $\ a^t\ $ congruent to? If $\ u>0\ $, what is $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}\ $ congruent to?

Comment: But $a^{t}$ can be -1 or 1. How do we know that he is always 1?

Comment: No, if $\ u>1\ $ (where $\ u\ $ is defined as in my previous comment) then $\ a^t\ $ will be neither $\ 1\ $ nor $\ -1\ $ mod $\ p\ $, but in that case $\ a^{2^it}\equiv-1\pmod{p}\ $, where $\ 0\le i=u-1\le s-1\ $, so it will be the *other* alternative of the given conditions which holds in this case. If $\ u=1\ $, then it *will* be the case that $\ a^t\equiv-1\pmod{p}\ $, but then you *still* have $\ a^{2^it}\equiv-1\pmod{p}\ $ for some $\ i\in\{0,1,\dots,s-1\}\ $—namely for $\ i=0\ $. Only in the case when $\ u=0\ $ will it be true that $\ a^t\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $.

Comment: Can you explain to me why when $u>1$ is neither -1 nor 1?

Comment: When $\ u>1 $, $\ a^{2^ut}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\ $, but $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}\ $, and $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}-1\equiv0\equiv\big(a^{2^{u-1}t}-1\big)\big(a^{2^{u-1}t}+1\big)\pmod{p}\ $, and since $\ \big(a^{2^{u-1}t}-1\big)\not\equiv0\pmod{p}\ $, we must have $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}\equiv-1\pmod{p}\ $. But $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}=\big(a^t\big)^{2^{u-1}}\ $, and $\ u-1\ge1\ $ so if $\ a^t\ $ were congruent to $1$ or $-1$ then $\ a^{2^{u-1}t}\ $ would have to be congruent to $1$.